# Как указать tablespace для индекса по столбцу при создании таблицы в Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Необходимо создать таблицу и в параметрах указать, что все создаваемые индексы должны располагаться в `tablespace indx`. Как это сделать? Нигде найти немогу.
Пытался так сделать, но ругается

```
create table Sell_information
( id integer,
  nazvanie varchar2(20) null,
-- nazvanie tovara
  telefon varchar2(10) null, -- phone prodavca
  kol_tovara number null,
  price number null,
  constraint tel_sell_info unique (telefon) tablespace indx,
  constraint id_sell_info primary key (id) tablespace indx
);
```

еще вариант

```
create table Sell_information
( id integer primary key using index (create index sell_info on Sell_information(id)),
  nazvanie varchar2(20) null,
-- nazvanie tovara
  telefon varchar2(10) null, -- phone prodavca
  kol_tovara number null,
  price number null,
  constraint tel_sell_info unique (telefon) tablespace indx
);
```

Неработает никак.

Comment: Не совсем к вопросу относится, но создавать модель данных на двух  языках очень плохая практика, т.е. ошибка проектирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли `using index`.

```
create table Sell_information( 
  id integer,
  nazvanie varchar2(20) null,
  telefon varchar2(10) null, -- phone prodavca
  kol_tovara number null,
  price number null,
  constraint tel_sell_info unique (telefon) using index tablespace indx,
  constraint id_sell_info primary key (id) using index tablespace indx
);
```

Надо добавить, что `tablespace` указывается не для столбца, а для индекса по столбцу.

Есть второй вариант создания констрейнтов и индексов, используя `alter table`

Сначала создадим таблицу

```
create table Sell_information( 
  id integer,
  nazvanie varchar2(20) null,
  telefon varchar2(10) null, -- phone prodavca
  kol_tovara number null,
  price number null
);
```

Потом добавит констрейнт и индекс по таблице

```
alter table Sell_information 
add constraint tel_sell_info unique (telefon) 
using index tablespace indx;
```

Comment: Не думал, что constraint т.е ограничение можно как констрейнт переводить, возьму на заметку.

Comment: Не берите, используйте нормальные русскоязычные термины, пожалуйста. :-)

Comment: Когда то давно, я тоже говорил "ограничение", а потом объяснял о чем речь. А констрейнт все сразу понимают, хотя в нашем языке такого слова и нет)